# Does statement_timeout need to be set within a function?

Tags: postgresql, pgbouncer

When I get a sudden spike in web users, some statements start queueing indefinitely, even though i'm setting a timeout like:

```
SET STATEMENT_TIMEOUT TO 5000; SELECT get_user_properties(12345);
```

Do functions ignore statement_timeout if it is not set within the function body?

I'm using postgresql 9.2 and pg_bouncer with session pooling.

Comment: Looks like setting it within the function doesn't work either. Is there a way to set statement_timeout per query?

Answer (score 5):

This works

```
BEGIN; SET SESSION STATEMENT_TIMEOUT TO 5000; COMMIT; SELECT get_user_properties(12345);
```